# Unable to see new features after installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, breeze

After installing ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2  I am unable to see any new features (e.g. new MVC4 SPA templates).

Initially, I installed via Web Platform Installer and after it didn't work, I uninstalled everything.
I then tried installing 2 MSI individual packages mentioned in Release Notes > Installation Notes. After successful installation I am still unable to see any new features.

My platform is :

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2012
Version 11.0.60115.01 Update 2 CTP
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.5.50709
```

Any ideas?

### Clarification

I am expecting new templates to show under

```
New Project -> Visual C# -> Web -> ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application (click ok) -> (shows only original 8 templates)
```

Comment: Are you first selecting "MVC 4 Internet Project" and then clicking "next"?

Comment: There is no "MVC 4 Internet Project" (see clarification). Do you mean "ASP.NET MVC 4 Web Application" (project) -> "Internet Application" (template) ? If so there is no "Next", only "Ok" but even so, there should be new templates at that level...

Comment: Which SPA templates are you talking about? There should be one "SPA" template which called Single Page Application...

Comment: look at the screenshots here (there should be 10 templates instead of 8) http://www.johnpapa.net/hottowel/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update contains **only one** [**SPA template.**](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/knockoutjs-template)

If you want to have the other SPA templates (like HotTowel) **you need to separately install them**: [Know a library other than Knockout?](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/introduction/other-libraries)

From [Announcing release of ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update:](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/02/18/announcing-release-of-asp-net-and-web-tools-2012-2-update.aspx) here are some links for the templates:

> If you don’t want to use the new Knockout template there are 4 new
>   community-created templates. These templates were built using the
>   improved [Custom MVC Template](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/fall-2012-update/custom-mvc-templates) support:
>
> - [BreezeJS template](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282649) that uses BreezeJS and Knockout for data binding and templating
> - [Ember template](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282647) uses the latest version of Ember and Handlebars
> - [DurandalJS template](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282648) is built using the new MVVM library DurandalJS as well as Knockout
> - [Hot Towel](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=282646) uses BreezeJS, DurandalJS, Knockout, require.js and Bootstrap

Comment: how can I tell that ASP.NET and Web Tools 2012.2 Update was installed? Should there be any version info in About or not?

Comment: In windows > Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features and look for the Microsoft Web Developer Tools 2012.2 - Visual Studio 2012

Answer (score 1):

## IMPORTANT

These MVC templates have been deprecated and don't work at all in VS 2013 (or after VS 2012.2 for that matter). Please don't use them.

Sadly, they will not be updated because the VSIX approach behind them has fallen out of favor ... mostly because it is far to difficult to write and maintain.

We suggest that you get started by following samples and videos. You can learn a lot from John Papa's two courses ["Building Apps with Angular and Breeze - Part 1"](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze) and ["...Part 2"](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/build-apps-angular-breeze-part2)